# jQuery - .load Not Working

Tags: jquery

I have to add an external page into a div, if i write this it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div[align=center]:eq(1)').append('<br /><a class="linkone" href="#">Link 1</a><div class="testing"></div>');

$(".linkone").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();            
            var thelink = $('.blockhead a').filter('a[href^="http://site.com/gallery/photo/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href');
            $(".testing").load("http://site.com/gallery/photo/showgallery.php?cat=1001 .forumrow table");
            });
 });
```

But if i write this it wont work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div[align=center]:eq(1)').append('<br /><a class="linkone" href="#">Link 1</a><div class="testing"></div>');

$(".linkone").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();            
            var thelink = $('.blockhead a').filter('a[href^="http://site.com/gallery/photo/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href');
            $(".testing").load("thelink .forumrow table");
            });
 });
```

How can I insert a variable after .load?

Comment: what is address of your site, because if its different than site.com then there is no way to load it by AJAX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(".testing").load(thelink+" .forumrow table");
```